# The distribution of random sum of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

There is a random variable $η$ with distribution continuous function $F(x)$ and a random variable $q$ with Poisson distribution with parameter $λ/µ$. What is the distribution of random sum of random variables $X(t)=η_1+η_2+...+η_{q(t)}$?

Comment: You might be interested in the notion of a [compound probability distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_probability_distribution), which is a not very self-evident name for a probability distribution with one or more parameters that are themselves random variables.

Comment: See for example [compound Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_Poisson_distribution).